# Align to the edge of the screen on iPhone X

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-x

How can I align a view to the top edge of the screen beyond the safe area?

[image]

Comment: Did either or both of the answers help you?

Comment: @vacawama What I want is to align to the top of the iPhone X status bar. The top edge of the screen.

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go ahead a select *Top Space to Safe Area* to create the top alignment constraint.  Then select that constraint in the Storyboard or the *Document Outline* and examine it in the *Attributes Inspector*.

Click on the **First Item** which is *Safe Area.Top* and in the pop-up select *Superview* to align it to the Superview instead of to the Safe Area.  Set the *Constant* to `0` and you're done.  Your view is now aligned to the top of the screen.

[image]

---

Here it is running in the iPhone X simulator with the *red view* aligned to the top of the screen:

[image: Running in iPhone X simulator]

Comment: Is this the correct way to do it? I mean, if I have a view with, let's say, a UILabel in it. Should I align the view to the `superview.top`, but align the label to `safe area.top`/`safeAreaInsets`? Or is there a better way to extend a UIView's color behind the notch, while still aligning to the safe area?

Comment: @JeroenJK, there's no way to extend a view's color without extending the view itself.  If all you are interested in is coloring the background, you can just set the `backgroundColor` of the main `view` of the `viewController`. If you want the background to be a picture that extends to the edges of the screen, you can add a `UIImageView` as a subview of `view` and you'd want that imageView to have the same frame as `self.view`.  The way to do that with *Auto Layout* is what I showed above.

Comment: The tools default to the *Safe Area* because they're trying to keep everything on screen for the new iPhones that have notches, so you have to put in a little extra effort to tell Interface Builder, I know this is going into the notch area, it's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom right of that view there are three or four buttons that help you set up constraints. One of them shows you a popup where it lets you create constraints for leading, trailing, top and bottom. (I think it's the second from the right. Xcode is updating right now and I can't open it to verify)

By default it will create the constraints to the safe area but there's a down arrow you can click and there you can choose the view as the constraint target. If you also set the constant to 0 then your view will be aligned at the top to the view.